# Minimalist posters 2 - Can you find the movie?

Tags: visual, movies

My friend wants to watch a movie, but it's never easy with her, so instead of telling me the title she gave me this :

[image]

> What is the movie ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Left 3:

> Movies featuring **Morgan Freeman**:
>
> Lucy
>
> The Dark Knight
>
> Oblivion

Right 3:

> Movies featuring **Brad Pitt**:
>
> Moneyball
>
> 12 Monkeys
>
> Troy

**Put together:**

> A movie featuring both Morgan Freeman and Brad Pitt:
>  **Se7en**

Comment: And its also will be the seventh movie in the puzzle.

Comment: @shyos Indeed. That hadn't occurred to me.  I'm not sure if that was intentional, but if not it's quite the coincidence!

Comment: Gongratulatiins ! the seventh movie thing was a coïncidence !

Comment: Can someone explain to me the connection between left movie #3 and the corresponding poster? (I was baffled by one key aspect of #1 but was able to find the necessary information on the web. #3 eludes me completely. As this may make obvious, I haven't seen the movie...)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Via [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV_Oblivion_cover.png)

Comment: Oh. That's too many layers of cultural knowledge I lack for this puzzle, then :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Don't feel bad.  I google image searched it `;)`

Comment: Now I feel stupid as well as ignorant.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:
MY guess at the movies, from left to right, are -

> ?, The Dark Knight, ?, Moneyball, Twelve Monkeys, The Wooden Horse (? means I don't know)

Not so sure how these lead to the final movie, though.